# Having trouble with def functions

Tags: python, function, nameerror

I have been taking this class for a bit with python for a bit and I have stumbled into a problem where any time I try to "def" a function, it says that it is not defined, I have no idea what I am doing wrong and this has become so frustrating.

```
# Define main
def main():
    MIN = -100
    MAX = 100
    LIST_SIZE = 10
#Create empty list named scores
scores = []
# Create a loop to fill the score list
for i in range(LIST_SIZE):  
    scores.append(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
    #Print the score list
    print(scores) 
    print("Highest Value: " + str(findHighest(scores)))
```

Every time I try to test run this, I get

> "builtins.NameError" name 'LIST SIZE' is not defined.

I cant take out the main function! It's required for the assignment, and even if I take it out I still run into errors.

Comment: The indentation is off. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indentation-in-python/

Comment: The entire body of the function should be indented.

Comment: Your class isn't teaching you the right things. Maybe get a different class. Variables declared in a function are scoped to that function. ie they aren't visible outside that function.

Comment: Well, if Python tells you that it isn't defined, then it isn't. Your `LIST_SIZE` is local to the `main` function (which btw you didn't even run), so you can't access it from anywhere else. I strongly recommend that you follow some good, well structured tutorial. See a list at https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MIN`, `MAX`, and `LIST_SIZE` variables are all being defined locally within `def main():`

By the looks of it, you want the code below those lines to be part of main, so fix the indentation to properly declare it as part of main.

```
def main():
    MIN = -100
    MAX = 100
    LIST_SIZE = 10

    #Create empty list named scores
    scores = []

    # Create a loop to fill the score list
    for i in range(LIST_SIZE):  
        scores.append(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        #Print the score list
        print(scores) 
        print("Highest Value: " + str(findHighest(scores)))
```

Comment: I can't believe it was something so simple as that. Thank you so much for the help and your answer! It's running smoothly now!

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

# Define main
def main():
    MIN = -100
    MAX = 100
    LIST_SIZE = 10
    #Create empty list named scores
    scores = []
    # Create a loop to fill the score list
    for i in range(LIST_SIZE):  
        scores.append(random.randint(MIN, MAX))
        #Print the score list
        print(scores) 
        print("Highest Value: " + str(findHighest(scores)))
main()
```

Output:

```py
[79]
```

**NOTE:** You will get another error message:

```
NameError: name 'findHighest' is not defined
```

Which I think `findHighest` should be a function in some part of your code.

Comment: Yes! I have that going later on into my code! Thank you for the help!